# Select em duas tabelas com count

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho duas tabelas no MySQL

```
clientes
id
nome
cat

categorias
id
nome
```

Preciso criar um `SELECT`, que mostre todas as categorias, mas apenas categorias que possui mais de 10 clientes (por exemplo).

Eu queria isso em apenas um `SELECT`, mas não estou conseguindo pensar como seria...

Tentei isso:

```
SELECT nome
  FROM categorias
 INNER JOIN clientes
    ON clientes.cat = categorias.id
 GROUP BY categorias.nome
HAVING COUNT(clientes.id) >=10
```

Comment: e já tentou algo? coloque na pegunta a query que tem até agora, se o problema são os 10 clientes, mostre a query sem esse critério

Comment: Tentei isso>: SELECT nome FROM categorias INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.cat = categorias.id GROUP BY categorias.nome having count (clientes.id) >=10

Answer (score 1):

Sua query está praticamente certa, o problema nela é, ambas as tabelas tem uma coluna chamada "nome", e isso vai dar referência ambigua, é preciso prefixar de qual tabela está usando a coluna:

```
SELECT categorias.nome 
  FROM categorias 
 INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.cat = categorias.id 
 GROUP BY categorias.nome 
having count (clientes.id) >=10
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui (coloquei a quantidade 5 para evitar fazer muitos inserts): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j8FBajK7tWnaU6oTrKJkV2/0

Pode mudar o count para `<= 3` e vai ver que tras mais categorias.

Comment: Ele gera esse erro: #1630 - FUNCTION test.count does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: veja o exemplo funcionando e comparare com seu código para ver o que tem de errado, o link mostra funcionando, baseado nos nomes de tabela e campos que pos na pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma `subquery` no `WHERE` para verificar quantos registros você tem na tabela `clientes` com a categoria da linha em questão:

```
SELECT cat.nome
  FROM categorias cat
 WHERE 10 <= (SELECT COUNT(1)
                FROM clientes cli
               WHERE cli.cat = cat.id)
```